# Visual Studio Code - Cucumber - Unable to find steps with special character

Tags: java, selenium, visual-studio-code, cucumber

I would like to ask for your assistance regarding the error I'm encountering in vscode and cucumber. I have a step where special character exists(?). In my Step definition file, I use "\\" next to the "?". But when I write it on my Feature file, it showing **Was unable to find step for "And user clicks on What this?"cucumberautocomplete** which is on yellow line.

Your replies are highly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Making this thread up

Answer (score 0):

Just use single \ to escape as given below

```
@Then("^user clicks on What this\?$")
```